# BibTex - how to make an exception in citing

Tags: bibtex, citing

I use the following template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl

I want to make an exception in case of one of the paper's citation. It should look like this in the text:

A. Backers, C. Durren et al., 2016

I.e. I want two first authors to be there, not just one.
In all other papers I do not want to change the default behavior.
No matter what I try, something is wrong in the text or in the references.

MWE:
If I put this to bibtex:
author={{Poper, A., Keruk, A.}, A. and {Keruk}, A. and {Poto}, A. and {Smolka}, B.},

In the text I see this:
Poper, A., Keruk, A. et al., 2015

But in the references this:
Poper, A., Keruk, A., A. et al. (2015).

So there is one "A." too much in references. And so on. So far I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/25077) Can you write a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/25077)?

Comment: The input format is completely wrong. This cannot be figured out by a program.